# Create Environment for Watson Discovery API

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I am trying to create an environment to start using my Watson Discovery Service created in Bluemix.

Following the get started documentation I entered this code (in cmd):

`curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "name":"my-first-environment", "description":"exploring environments", "size":0}' "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments?version=2016-12-01"`

I made sure I entered the right service credentials but I get this error that I don´t understand:

> `{ "code" : 401 , "error" : "Not Authorized" , "description" : "2017-05-23T08:53:35-04:00, Error ERCDPLTFRM-INVLDCHR occurred when accessing https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments?version=2016-12-01, Tran-Id: gateway-dp02-1408488112 - " }`

When I type the link in a browser and enter the credentials manually I don't get any error.

Does some body understand this error and can help me?

Thanks in advance and best Regards

Emira

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you are supplying Discovery Service credentials? If you then check that you have the username and password the right way round.

When you access Discovery Service, have some option with the name: *Service Credentials*.

Replace the `username` and `password` with these values.

See one example to access:

[image]

```
curl -X POST -u "USERNAME":"PASSWORD" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "name":"my-first-environment", "description":"exploring environments", "size":0}' "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments?version=2016-12-01"
```

EDIT:

```
 curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "name": "test_collection", "description": "My test collection", "configuration_id": "{configuration_id}" }' "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections?version=2016-12-01"
```

Comment: Yes.. I am sure I replaced with the right credentials!

Comment: With the last cURL I get back the following error:

curl: (3) Illegal port number
curl: (3) Illegal port number
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 7
{
  "code": 400,
  "error": "Unexpected token '"
}

Comment: Try again. Are you trying create a collection or add some document? The last edit was for add document. And this now is for create a collection... based on your example is the same

Comment: Replace with YOUR configuration id and enviroment id. I test and works perfectly